# How can I get z position of hector_quadrotor in ROS?

Tags: c++, simulation, ros, robotics

I am trying to get z position of hector_quadrotor in simulation. I can get X and Y axis coordinates but I couldn't get Z coordinate. I tried to get it by using GPS but the values are not correct. So I want to get Z coordinate by using barometer or another sensor.

Here the a part of pose_estimation_node.cpp (You can find full version on github source):

```
void PoseEstimationNode::gpsCallback(const sensor_msgs::NavSatFixConstPtr& gps, const 
geometry_msgs::Vector3StampedConstPtr& gps_velocity) {
  boost::shared_ptr<GPS> m = boost::static_pointer_cast<GPS>(pose_estimation_->getMeasurement("gps"));

  if (gps->status.status == sensor_msgs::NavSatStatus::STATUS_NO_FIX) {
    if (m->getStatusFlags() > 0) m->reset(pose_estimation_->state());
    return;
  }

  GPS::Update update;
  update.latitude = gps->latitude * M_PI/180.0;
  update.longitude = gps->longitude * M_PI/180.0;
  update.velocity_north =  gps_velocity->vector.x;
  update.velocity_east  = -gps_velocity->vector.y;
  m->add(update);

  if (gps_pose_publisher_ || sensor_pose_publisher_) {
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped gps_pose;
    pose_estimation_->getHeader(gps_pose.header);
    gps_pose.header.stamp = gps->header.stamp;
    GPSModel::MeasurementVector y = m->getVector(update, pose_estimation_->state());

    if (gps_pose_publisher_) {
      gps_pose.pose.position.x = y(0);
      gps_pose.pose.position.y = y(1);
      gps_pose.pose.position.z = gps->altitude - pose_estimation_->globalReference()- >position().altitude;
      double track = atan2(gps_velocity->vector.y, gps_velocity->vector.x);
      gps_pose.pose.orientation.w = cos(track/2);
      gps_pose.pose.orientation.z = sin(track/2);
      gps_pose_publisher_.publish(gps_pose);
    }

    sensor_pose_.pose.position.x = y(0);
    sensor_pose_.pose.position.y = y(1);
    """I add it here""" 
  }
}
```

If I add ----->   sensor_pose_.pose.position.z = gps->altitude,

I can get a Z coordinate on RVIZ simulation or gnome-terminal. But as I said, the values are very meanless (negative values).

Also ------> gps_pose.pose.position.z = gps->altitude - pose_estimation_->globalReference()-
>position().altitude;

It is not working because position().altitude return NAN.
There are another measurement method in pose_estimation_node.cpp like barometer. How can I use barometer value.

Here the another part of pose_estimation_node.cpp:

```
#if defined(USE_HECTOR_UAV_MSGS)
void PoseEstimationNode::baroCallback(const hector_uav_msgs::AltimeterConstPtr& 
altimeter) {
  boost::shared_ptr<Baro> m = boost::static_pointer_cast<Baro>(pose_estimation_->getMeasurement("baro"));
  m->add(Baro::Update(altimeter->pressure, altimeter->qnh));
}

#else
void PoseEstimationNode::heightCallback(const geometry_msgs::PointStampedConstPtr& 
height) {
boost::shared_ptr<Height> m = boost::static_pointer_cast<Height>(pose_estimation_->getMeasurement("height"));

Height::MeasurementVector update;
update(0) = height->point.z;
m->add(Height::Update(update));

if (sensor_pose_publisher_) {
sensor_pose_.pose.position.z = height->point.z - m->getElevation();
  }
}
#endif

void PoseEstimationNode::magneticCallback(const geometry_msgs::Vector3StampedConstPtr& magnetic) {
boost::shared_ptr<Magnetic> m = boost::static_pointer_cast<Magnetic>(pose_estimation_->getMeasurement("magnetic"));

Magnetic::MeasurementVector update;
update.x() = magnetic->vector.x;
update.y() = magnetic->vector.y;
update.z() = magnetic->vector.z;
m->add(Magnetic::Update(update));

if (sensor_pose_publisher_) {
sensor_pose_yaw_ = -(m->getModel()->getTrueHeading(pose_estimation_->state(), update) - pose_estimation_->globalReference()->heading());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a barometer you need to actually add that sensor to your robot. What you're looking at is only the callback meaning such messages are supported. If you want to add a new sensor to your robot I'd suggest looking at [this tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=add_laser).

All that being said, if you're getting incorrect altitude values you need to go back and recheck your transforms because the localization built into hector should work fine.